# problem with buffer of byte long much 1MB

Tags: delphi, file, memory-management

as i can solve this problem:  i want use a buffer of byte of 1 MB or more, with array it not is possible becouse i have a stack overlflow. I have thinked about getmem and freemem, or using tmemorystream, but not have understood exactely as solve it. To me need for use a buffer for copy a file using tfilestream with read/write. 
I don't want load all fine in one time in memory and after write it in disk all in time too; for it, i have found solution, but not need me it.
Thanks very much. Daniela.

Comment: Using memory functions instead of arrays because you get OF errors is a bad strategy. Try to understand why you get a stack overflow. You're probably in a loop or in a recursive function, the problem is more like you have made a programming error in a loop.

Comment: Actually, his problem *is* with the array allocation. It does not have anything to do with recursion. 1 MB a normal stack size, so if he wants to use such a large chunk of memory, he *must* move to the heap.

Comment: @az0 the total size of a typical stack is 1MB(I think you can tell the linker to change it, but that's not the right thing here). So allocating a 1MB array on the stack is wrong, and is the OPs problem. Allocating big data on the heap is the right thing to do.

Comment: @az01 you seem to be asserting that you can allocate any size of data structure on the heap. That's plain wrong.

Comment: No, what I'm asserting is that a stack overflow is always coming from a bug inside a loop.

Comment: @David: Any chance you meant to refer to either myself or CodeInChaos? I don't see how az01's comment has anything to do with what you just said.

Comment: @David and Ken: I don't know how Delphi is handling the "make stack frame" CPU instruction. My comment was a misunderstanding. However, I've never seen a stack overflow which was not triggered in a loop.

Comment: @az01 your assertion is not true. Allocate a local variable larger than the stack and you will see what I mean.n the stack and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @az01: You're right that stack overflows usually occurs in a loop or via recursion. But in this particular case, Danny is simply absorbing his entire stack frame by allocating an extremely large data structure. Even without loops or recursion, trying to grab over 1 MB of stack memory is doomed to fail.

Comment: You guys are just driving me mad with your superb absolute knowledge...You are just upper, whathever our level is...I just feel stupid right now.

Comment: Solution is simple allocate you buffer on heap instead of stack. Stack size is controlled by $MAXSTACKSIZE compiler directive

Answer (score 3):

If you have a stack overflow then your variable doesn't fit on the stack. You are clearly using a local variable.

Solve the problem by using the heap instead. Either `GetMem` or `SetLength`.

Answer (score 2):

One easy solution is using a dynamic array. Their data is allocated on the heap, so you will avoid the stackoverflow. The advantage of them over directly working with memory allocation functions is that they are refcounted and the memory they allocated will automatically be freed once the last reference goes out of scope.

```
var buffer:array of byte;
begin
  SetLength(buffer,100000);
  ...
  //Will be freed here as buffer goes out of scope
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your buffer variable is allocated on stack and default maximum stack size used by Delphi compiler is 1 MiB. So the solution is to set higher limit by using project options or the following global directive:

```
{$MAXSTACKSIZE 4194304} // eg. now maximum is 4 MiB
```

Other way is to use heap instead of stack, any of dynamically allocated memory, in your case probably best solution will be a dynamic array.

Performance note: stack is faster than heap.

Comment: Increasing stack size carries dangers. Each thread in the app needs to reserve that virtual memory. Bumping it up puts pressure on address space. Heap is the way to go for large blocks.

Comment: @David Heffernan, stack is cheap in 32-bit Windows, so these "dangers" is not practical issue to worry about.

Comment: It is not that cheap with multi core machines. 4gb address space can get eaten up quickly with 64 way machine and 4mb stack, say.

Comment: -1. Increasing the stack is **absolutely** not the correct solution.

Comment: @Andriy M, thanks, that made the answer even more correct. @Ken White, you dont know for sure. @David Heffernan, thats an assumption about target environment, details of which weren't released yet by taciturn OP (at least publicly).

Comment: Most calls to `CreateThread` pass 0 for stack size which results in the process default, which you just changed to 4MB. Often you don't control all of the threads in your app.

Comment: Most calls (including `TThread`), which means if you use any `TThread` based threads in your app (or any of your third party components/libraries do), it increases the stack for *all* of them. So not  only do you provide a non-solution to the actual problem, but you add additional ones (or extra work to implement your own threads via the API). As I said, this is *almost never* the correct solution. (And I *do* know that for sure.)

Comment: @David Heffernan, "oftenly" having **rogue** threads elsewhere is not an excuse.